# Pandas Profiling KeyError

Tags: pandas-profiling

When running below code, running into error *KeyError: 'Requested level (var1) does not match index name (None)'*.  I used python=3.7, jupyterlab=2.1.4, pandas-profiling=2.8.  I tried to install previous pandas-profiling versions. But had the same error. I'd appreciate if anyone has any idea what went wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(100, 5),
    columns=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
)

ProfileReport(df)
```

**See below snippet for detailed error message:**

[Detailed error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUItG.png)

Answer (score 0):

That problem disappeared after I upgraded pandas profiling to the latest version.

pandas-profiling (2.3.0) -> Latest: 2.8.0

Comment: Do you run this line in the Jupyter notebook or the terminal? I get the error message `Input In [17]
    pandas-profiling (2.3.0) -> Latest: 2.8.0
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax `